# Incorrect evaluation of the irreducibility of the polynomial

Tags: c++, polynomials, polynomial-math, ntl, finite-field

in my function `PolynomialIrreducibility()` I'm evaluating if entered polynomial is irreducible or not over **GF(prime_number)**.

```
void PolynomialIrreducibility () {

    // Enter prime number
    ZZ prime_number;
    ZZ_pX polynom;

    do {
        cout << "Enter prime number: ";
        cin >> prime_number;
    } while (!ProbPrime(prime_number));

    ZZ_p::init(prime_number);   // define GF(prime_number)

    // Enter n
    long n;
    do {
        cout << "Enter n: ";
        cin >> n;
    } while (n < 1);

    BuildIrred(polynom, n);     // generate an irreducible polynomial P of degree n over GF(prime_number)

    ZZ_pE::init(polynom);       // define GF(prime_number^n)

    // Enter polynom
    ZZ_pX input_polynom;
    cout << "Enter polynom: ";
    cin >> input_polynom;
        
    ZZ_pEX convert_polynom;
    conv(convert_polynom, input_polynom);
    
    if (DetIrredTest(convert_polynom)) {
    //if (ProbIrredTest(convert_polynom)) {
    //if (IterIrredTest(convert_polynom) {

        cout << "-> Irreducible polynomial" << endl;
    }
    else {

        cout << "-> Reducible polynomial" << endl;      
    }
}
```

While testing implemented function with irreducible polynomial x^2 + x + 2 all three functions (DetIrredTest, ProbIrredTest, IterIrredTest) for determining if polynomial is irreducible or not evaluate that it is even though it isn't irreducible over GF(3) as shown below.

```
Enter prime number: 3
Enter n: 2
Enter polynom: [2 1 1]
-> Reducible polynomial
```

Please, am I evaluating the irreducibility in the wrong way or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: What does `conv` do?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm it is [converting](https://libntl.org/doc/conversions.txt) ZZ_pX to ZZ_pEX because later in the program I need this form for factorization. You can validate `input_polynom` without conversion and the result will be the same.

Comment: x^2+x+1 is irreducible over GF(3) but reducible over GF(9). Is this not the result you're getting?

Comment: I updated my answer to include examples of irreducible polynomials in GF(3).

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue as commented by aschepler, a irreducible polynomial of degree n in GF(p) is not irreducible in GF(p^n). It will have n roots. I suggest making this change so that DetIrredTest() operates in GF(p):

```
    BuildIrred(polynom, 1);     // build irreducible poly of degree 1
```

---

I found three irreducible polynomials in GF(3) that can be used as reducing polynomials for GF(9):

```
x^2       + 1     irreducible  (x + 1 is a primitive element)
x^2 +   x + 2     primitive    (x     is a primitive element)
x^2 + 2 x + 2     primitive    (x     is a primitive element)
```

Comment: working with NTL library [2 1 1] represents 2 + x + x^2